# Input box prompting for second data entry to store data, can we make it store on the first entry?

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I am trying to put an activex textbox over a cell (B23), which is hiding the text cell with the secure data. The textbox has the passwordchar set to *. When I put the input box function in the textbox it pops up when they start to type, then when I push okay the box clears and asks me to reenter my data then it saves to B23. Is there a way to make this work on the first time, or if on the second popup have it say "please verify your entry"?

I've tried linking the cell to B23 and taking the range off, but its not storing the data.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  Dim response As String
  response = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the EIN/Tax Payer ID with no dashes or spaces. For security purposes this information will disappear after entry and be stored securely.", Title:="Tax Payer Data", Default:="Enter Tax Payer ID here")
   Range("B23").Value = response
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make this work on the first time, or if on the second popup have it say "please verify your entry"? I am trying to hide sensitive data (EIN, bank account number, etc) after it is entered, but keeping the starting "0"'s and the excel sheet is already formatted to show zeros. So whether we stick with the text box over the cell or something different I am open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GotFocus event should help you

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    Dim response As String
  response = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the EIN/Tax Payer ID with no dashes or spaces. For security purposes this information will disappear after entry and be stored securely.", Title:="Tax Payer Data", Default:="Enter Tax Payer ID here")
   Range("G1").Value = response
   TextBox1.Text = response
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: This made my day!! Thank you so much!

Comment: As an alternative approach, see this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-display-cell-values-c94b3493-7762-4a53-8461-fb5cd9f05c33. Just a word of caution, you shouldnt really be saving client data in a plain excel though

Comment: This file is going to be pretty locked down once it's finalized. We also have B23 feeding to a hidden and locked sheet for security.

When I did the ";;;"  it removed the starting zeros.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Excel **ever** with sensitive data. There are holes in its security.